# Max pressure of hydraulic mtb lever

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

i'm considering a machine build based on MTB hydraulic lever brake and I would like to know if the lever, pushed by hand, will handle 13 bars /190 PSI ?
I'm really new to this kind of measurement.

Comment: It may be helpful to know if you mean just the lever blade itself, or all the seals and other bits in the lever assembly, or everything in the entire lever/hose/caliper system.

Comment: An average adult grip strength is about [300 Newtons](http://www.economist.com/news/science-and-technology/21651169-strength-your-handshake-predicts-length-your-life-getting-grip) with top third of men at 500 N. Over an area of say, around 2 square inches (guesstimate) gives about 2-4 bar of pressure exerted by a human hand. So, my guess is that since you're going to a factor of 3x to what an strong human can produce, it might be out of the safety margin. But you could presumably build a test rig and actually test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asuming 300 N as average grip multiplied by a leverage ratio of 10 it is 3000 N of axial force. the piston diameter is about 10 mm so the piston effective area will be 0.785 squared mm. so the presure could be 3000 N/ .785 cm2 = 3821.7 N/cm2 equal to 5542 PSI. so it can handle almost 30 times what you need.
the problem is: lack of power if you can only apply 190 PSI maybe the brakes wont work at all.